# Typecasting structure pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Hie guys. I am studying structures and pointers using the book called `Pointers in C: A Hands on Approach` and on page 107, I came across an incomplete example of struct type casting. I tried to make it work by just implementing the function `receivedata()` ,adding headers and making a few changes.

This is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct signature
{
    char  sign;
    char version;
};

struct id
{
    char id;
    char platform;
};

struct data
{
    struct id idv;
    struct signature sig;
    char data[100];
};

static void receivedata(struct data *d);
static struct signature *extractsignature(struct data *d);
static struct id *extractid(struct data *d);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
/* Actual line in book is :
*  struct data *img; with no memory allocation or assignment to NULL.
*  Had errors so i allocated memory on the heap before passing the value to 
*  Receivedata(); */
    struct data *img = malloc(sizeof(struct data));

    receivedata(img);

/* Actual line in book is :
 *   struct id *idval = extractid(&img);
 *   struct signature *sig = extractsignature(&img);
 * This is obviously erroneous because &img is a pointer 
 * to a pointer (struct data**) which is not the data type for 
 * the extract functions' argument */
    struct id *idval = extractid(img);
    struct signature *sig = extractsignature(img);

    printf("For signature:\n");
    printf("sign = %c", sig->sign);
    printf(" version = %c\n\n", sig->version);

    printf("For id:\n");
    printf("id = %c", idval->id);
    printf(" platform = %c", idval->platform);

    printf("\ndata = %s", img->data);

    return 0;
}

static struct signature *extractsignature(struct data *d)
{
    struct signature *sig = (struct signature *)d;
    return sig;
}

static struct id *extractid(struct data *d)
{
    struct id *idv = (struct id *)d;
    return idv;
}

static void receivedata(struct data *d)
{
    struct data *dptr = d;
    char *ch = "CODING IS COOL!";

    dptr->sig.sign = 's';
    dptr->sig.version = '1';

    dptr->idv.id = 'i';
    dptr->idv.platform = 'p';

    strncpy(dptr->data, ch, strlen(ch));

    return;
}
```

What I would like to understand is the casting inside the function `extractid()` and `extraxtsignature()` because it seems we are casting `struct data *` so as to retrieve its individual members. I ran the program and what i get is the value of the first member of `struct data` for both sig member and id members. Here is the output when `struct id` comes first in the `struct data`:

```
For signature:
sign = i version = p

For id:
id = i platform = p
data = CODING IS COOL!
```

and this when `struct signature` is the first element:

```
For signature:
sign = s version = 1

For id:
id = s platform = 1
data = CODING IS COOL!
```

and finally, this when `char data[100]` is the first element:

```
For signature:
sign = C version = O

For id:
id = C platform = O
data = CODING IS COOL!
```

May you please explain this type of casting, when to use it and the best practices. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct data
{
    struct id idv;
    struct signature sig;
    char data[100];
};
```

For the above definition, the `extractid` function below is valid and will get right results.

```
static struct id *extractid(struct data *d)
{
    struct id *idv = (struct id *)d;
    return idv;
}
```

This is because, `struct id` is the first member of the `struct data`. So, when you have `struct data *d`, the `d` points to the starting address of `struct data` and which is same as the starting address of the first member `struct id`.

So, if you are casting for the first member of the struct, then it is right as per the code you have provided above.

Comment: Thanks @Sri.U. So are you saying that it does not work for the second member? i.e `extractsignature()` is invalid for the above definition

Comment: yes, because, the d is pointing to id. since the signature and id have the same type of members (i.e., 2 char members), in this case, it prints the value of id and platform for sign and version respectively.

Comment: your pointer needs to move to the right offset/address, so that it points to the exact location of signature, for that to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I almost get it now but when do u use it and Why not just do it like :   ` struct id *idv = &d->idv; `? It kind of solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, that is the straight forward way of doing that. No need to do this(whatever in extractid), unless you have some specific use case.
Also, in terms of coding, ` struct id *idv = &d->idv; ` is more intuitive. But, this is just my opinion.

Comment: I think the exercise may have been just to demonstrate how you can use pointers to do such a thing. More for understanding. It is not recommending people to use such a thing.

Comment: I guess so. @Sri.U I think I am happy now. Thank you

Comment: Also, if you want to do something similar for extractsignature, you can do something like this in the extractsignature function. Get the offset of member `sig` using offset = offsetof(struct data, sig): Then do `struct signature *sig = (struct signature *)((char *)d + offset) ;`

Comment: I tried that a long time ago but failed because I did not know I was supposed to cast the `d` to `(char *)`. Perfect, now it works with the offset that I calculated `offset = 2`. Informative indeed

Comment: read about pointer arithmetic to understand why it should be done that way in this case.